# How to change El Capitan resolution in VirtualBox?

Tags: osx, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution

**I tried:**
Editing file `com.apple.Boot.plist` by adding:

```
<key>Graphics Mode</key>
<string>1280x1024x32</string>
```

---

Modifying VM settings by executing this line in terminal:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "ElCapitan" CustomVideoMode1 1280x1024x32
```

---

Another terminal method:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "ElCapitan" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode 3
```

---

None of the above methods worked for me. Every time I start El Capitan VM, it runs in 1024x768 resolution. I remember that about year ago, when I used Windows as host, it worked. Now I use Ubuntu. Can that be a reason it's not working anymore?

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above steps on El Capitan (host: Manjaro).

What worked for me was:

VBoxManage setextradata "mac" "VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution" "1920x1080"

Ref: https://superuser.com/a/1264540